# Как узнать область видимости свойства объекта

Tags: php, ооп

**Есть такой код:**

```
class test
{
    private $a = 0;
    protected $b = 0;
    public $c = 0;

    public function echoprop()
    {
        foreach($this as $key => $val)
        {
            echo "$".$key." = ".$val.";\n";
        }
    }
}
$var = new test;
$var->echoprop();
```

Если его запустить то он выведет все свойства объекта, но мне бы не помешало узнать область видимости каждого свойства.

P.S `var_dump` не предлагать так как он выводит целиком информацию.

Comment: используйте [ReflectionClass::getProperties()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)

Comment: @korytoff мне ниже уже хороший ответ написали =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуй вот так.

```
<?php
class test
{
    private $a = 0;
    protected $b = 0;
    public $c = 0;

    public function echoprop()
    {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));

        foreach($this as $key => $val)
        {
            $prop = $reflector->getProperty($key);
            if( $prop->isPrivate() ) {
                echo 'Private';
            } else if( $prop->isProtected() ) {
                echo 'Protected';
            } else if( $prop->isPublic() ) {
                echo 'Public';
            }

            echo "$".$key." = ".$val.";\n";
        }
    }
}
$var = new test;
$var->echoprop();
```

Еще могу предложить такой извращенный вариант :) без ReflectionClass.
PHP функция `get_class_vars` возвращает массив методов класса которые находятся в области видимости этой функции.

То есть так можно получить все методы по из видимости.

```
class test
{
    private $a = 0;
    protected $b = 0;
    public $c = 0;

    public function getVisibleProps()
    {
        return get_class_vars(get_class($this));
    }
}

class testExtend extends test

{
    public function getVisibleProps()
    {
        return get_class_vars(get_class($this));
    }
}

$var = new test;
$allPublicProtectedPrivateProps = $var->getVisibleProps();

$varExtend = new testExtend();
$allPublicProtectedPropers = $varExtend ->getVisibleProps();

$allPublicProps = get_class_vars(get_class($var));
```

Далее необходимо просто получить расхождения `allPublicProtectedPrivateProps`, `allPublicProtectedPropers` и `$allPublicProps` и получить соответствующие свойства с их областями видимости.

И вот еще одно решение. Но нуждается в парсинге.

```
class test 
{ 
    public $var1 = 1; 
    protected $var2 = 2; 
    private $var3 = 3; 
    static $var4 = 4; 

    public function toArray() 
    { 
        return (array) $this; 
    } 
} 

$t = new test; 
print_r($t->toArray()); 

/* outputs: 

Array 
( 
    [var1] => 1 
    [ * var2] => 2 
    [ test var3] => 3 
) 

*/
```

По ключу можно понять область видимости.

Но это слишком уж извращенно получается - ну не по программистски так сказать :)

Comment: Про данный класс слышал =) Кстати, а нельзя обойтись без него?

Comment: плюс, тут метка ооп будет излишне потому как вы уже дали верный ответ, и от присутствие метки ни как не измениться смысл вопроса... Я пока пропустил эту правка но не думаю что её примут.

Comment: @MaximPro выше в ответе добавил вариант без ReflectionClass :)

Comment: @DanielAbyan Дичь без `ReflectionClass`

Comment: @MaximPro Дааа. Ну я думаю еще будут интересные решения - самому интересно стало :D

Comment: @DanielAbyan Мне кажется есть еще какие-то функции из php, которыми можно добиться, но по сравнению с `ReflectionClass` им не переплюнуть его

Comment: Да ReflectionClass мощный инструмент. Кстати еще одно решение добавил.

Comment: @DanielAbyan Да вот только print_r, такой же почти как и var_dump, он не видит static переменные, как увидеть?

Comment: @MaximPro print_r для примера я там записал. Ты можешь это значение просто по for each прокатить.

Comment: @DanielAbyan А что насчет static свойств, как их определить? Ни один из способов их не видит

Comment: @MaximPro Можно вызвать `$reflector->getStaticProperties()` но этот метод вернет только массив статичных свойств. Но область видимости статичного метода вроде получить слишком сложно.

Comment: @DanielAbyan спасибо